# SetTimeout not working in chrome snippets

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, code-snippets

I'm writing a code snippet in google chrome to aggregate some data.

For some reason my timeout isn't working, here's a very simplified vers...

```js
let element= document.querySelector(".element");
let link = element.querySelector("a");

link.click();

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("waited");
},500);

console.log("waiting");
```

My output :

```
waiting
undefined
Navigated to http://127.0.0.1/page.html
```

My expected output would be :

```
undefined
Navigated to http://127.0.0.1/page.html
waiting
waited
```

It's also strange to me that the output would be reversed as well.

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Is `undefined` and `Naviagted to ...` are not logs but an error and an action?

Comment: undefined is because I'm assigning a variable in chrome console, navigated to is because I'm changing page with link.click()

Comment: The page has to be fetched before it can be navigated to, this is async. The synchronous calls inside your function will all occur before this function returns, so the `undefined` log should be the last of synchronous logs. Once navigated, your document is removed and all the timers associated with it are canceled.

Answer (score 1):

After `link.click()`, it takes a long time to really navigate the page.
Due to asynchronous nature of Javascript, following lines of code will be executed until the real navigation takes place. So,

```
console.log("waiting");
```

will take place. But

```
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("waited");
}, 500);
```

will not take place because the real navigation will occur before 500ms.

After the real navigation, your codes will be gone unless it takes in place.

```
document.body.innerHTML = '' +
        '<div class="element">'+
        '    <a href="#"></a>' +
        '</div>'; 

let element= document.querySelector(".element");
let link = element.querySelector("a");

link.click();

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("waited");
}, 500);

console.log("waiting");
```

The log of this snippet is:

```
waiting
undefined
waited
```